# Cor da fonte do DBGrid no Delphi Berlin

Tags: delphi-berlin, dbgrid

estou com dificuldades para alterar a cor do texto dos registros exibidos em DBGgrid no Delphi Berlin (10.1 update 1). Ao tentar alterar a cor da fonte e ativar o itálico e o negrito, todos os registros aparecem corretamente exceto o registro selecionado que exibe o texto duplicado, um com as alterações de fonte e outro sem alteração nenhuma. 
Vale ressaltar que fonte a baixo é apenas para teste por isso altera a cor de todos os registros no sistema haverá situações onde essa cor será alterada ou não.
Segue a baixo trecho do código e imagem que ilustra o problema.

```
procedure TForm2.DBGrid1DrawColumnCell(Sender: TObject; const Rect: TRect;
  DataCol: Integer; Column: TColumn; State: TGridDrawState);
begin
  TDBGrid(Sender).Canvas.Font.Style := [fsItalic, fsBold];
  TDBGrid(Sender).Canvas.Font.Color := clMaroon;

  TDBGrid(Sender).Canvas.FillRect(Rect);
  TDBGrid(Sender).DefaultDrawColumnCell(Rect, DataCol, Column, State);
end;
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mesmo postando a dúvida no Delphi Experts,não obtive uma resposta satisfatória, mas vou por aqui as duas soluções encontradas:

1: Evitar o código de formatação sempre que o registro estiver selecionado. Dessa forma o texto duplicado não ocorre pois o sistema não gera o texto formatado. Ex:

```
procedure TForm2.DBGrid1DrawColumnCell(Sender: TObject; const Rect: TRect;
  DataCol: Integer; Column: TColumn; State: TGridDrawState);
begin
  if gdSelected in State then
    Exit;

  TDBGrid(Sender).Canvas.Font.Style := [fsItalic, fsBold];
  TDBGrid(Sender).Canvas.Font.Color := clMaroon;

  TDBGrid(Sender).Canvas.FillRect(Rect);
  TDBGrid(Sender).DefaultDrawColumnCell(Rect, DataCol, Column, State);
end;
```

2: O `DBGrig` dos Delphis mais novos (não me lembro a partir de qual versão) possui uma propriedade chamada `DrawingStyle` que no Berlin vem setada com `gdsThemed`, isso indica ao sistema que deve gerar o DBGrid de acordo com o tema do Windows, com essa propriedade a forma do texto apresenta o erro que mencionei. Se essa propriedade for alterada para `gdsClassic` o DBGird não seguirá o tema do Windows mas irá formatar corretamente o conteúdo de usas células.

Fica a critério de cada um escolher qual a melhor forma. Se existir outra forma por favor informem pois gostaria de tentar.

Comment: o Que O Benjamim Falou é verdade eu passei por esse problema e no neste [site](http://www.rodrigomourao.com.br/dica-do-bruto-corrigindo-problema-no-dbgrid-em-projetos-migrados-do-delphi-7/) eu achei uma maneira de corrigir ou de amenizar a situação